# Comparison between pointer and integer C++ forbidden

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement, integer, c-strings

Hey so i'm still learning C++ and i've ran into a snag while compiling this part of my code. Before i go any further with the text game that I'm developing for a project i'd like to know why I am getting this error when attempting to compile so I can debug as I develop.

> ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive] if (answer1 == 'Yes' && answer1 == 'yes) {

I'm not exactly sure where i am going wrong because the code is storing the result as "Yes". (I checked by adding a std::cout >> answer1; after gathering the users y/n answer.)

but when i try to check that with the If statement i get this error.

```
    #include <iostream>

int main() {

  char name[50];
  char answer1[50];

  std::cout << "Ahh... Welcome newcomer. What is your name?\n";
  std::cin >> name;
  std::cout << "You said your name was " << name << " correct?\n";
  std::cin >> answer1;

    // Let the game begin!

  if (answer1 == 'Yes' && answer1 == 'yes') {

    std::cout << "Lets get this game started then!\n";

  }
  else {

    std::cout << "Then why are you even wasting my time?\n";
  }

}
```

I know it's basic and rudimentary but I am still learning (self-taught, too). Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why do you use C-strings in C++? You really should use strings

Comment: On a side note, since `name` and `answer1` are `char[]` arrays, `std::cin >> name;` and `std::cin >> answer1;` are buffer overflows waiting to happen. Use the `std::setw()` stream manipulator to limit how many characters `operator>>` can read into each array. Or else use the `std::cin.get(char*, std::streamsize)` method to read into the arrays.  Or, just stop using `char[]` arrays and use `std::string` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think i am going to switch the std::string until I can fully understand the other half of your comment. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `answer1` is declared as a character array

```
char answer1[50];
```

In the condition of this if statement

```
if (answer1 == 'Yes' && answer1 == 'yes') {
```

the array designator is converted implicitly to pointer to its first element (character) that is has the type `char *`.

On the other hand, for example this literal `'Yes'` is a multibyte character literal that has the type `int`.

So you are trying to compare the address of the first character of an array with an integer that has implementation defined value. It is obvious that this does not make sense.

What you need is to use the standard C function `strcmp` that is declared in the header `<cstring>`. And instead of character literals use string literals.

Also you have to use the logical OR operator `||` instead of the logical AND operator `&&` inside the condition.

For example

```
#include <cstring>

//…

if ( strcmp( answer1, "Yes" ) == 0 || strcmp( answer1, "yes" ) == 0 ) {
```

The program will be more safer if instead of character arrays you will use the standard class `std::string`.

Comment: This answer worked for me, thank you. Do you mind explaining a little more why there is "== 0" afterwards? What is this doing?

Comment: @DylanBarnes If the both strings are equal each other then the function strcmp returns 0.

Comment: @DylanBarnes [Documentation for `strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Answer (score 1):

This: `'Yes'` is a character literal, not a string literal. Multi-character literals have implementation-defined values of type `int`, and are not what you want to be using. They are an obscure language feature that is rarely useful, but they seem to be a common stumbling block for new programmers.

You would want this:

```
if (answer1 == "Yes" && answer1 == "yes")
```

except that you've defined `answer` as a character array. The comparison would compile, but it wouldn't do what you want. It would compare the `char*` pointer values, not the contents of the strings, and the comparison would always fail.

Using `std::string`, defined in the `<string>` header, would let you do the comparison using the overloaded `==` operator. (To compare C-style strings stored in character arrays, you'd have to use `strcmp()` declared in `<cstring>`, but there's little point in doing that in C++.)

Comment: I am still a little unsure as to how I would apply your solution using "std::string". To clarify, would instead of using "std::cin >> answer1;" to receive my input i use "std::string >> answer1;" to store the answer into the "answer1" variable?

Comment: @DylanBarnes He means `char answer1[50];` becomes `std::string answer1;` and `std::cin >> answer1;` stays `std::cin >> answer1;`.

Comment: @user4581301 Excellent. Thank you.